# Why doesn't C++ allow two function/class templates with the same name, differing only by the type of a non-type template parameter (of integral type)?

Tags: c++

The compiler gives an error when I try this. I tried with both VC++ and g++.

This applies equally to function templates and class templates (though for function templates the compiler error only occurs if and when the function template is instantiated; the compiler error for class template occurs immediately when the compiler encounters the second class definition).

Here is an example for a function template:

```
template <unsigned int>
void Foo() {}

template <signed int>    // Same name, only difference is the type of the
void Foo() {}            // non-type template parameter (of integral type)

Foo<10U>(); // COMPILER ERROR.
```

Above, why can't the compiler just instantiate `Foo<unsigned int>()`?

I found that this is *not* an issue if the second version of the template function/class has a type template parameter. It also is *not* an issue if the second version of the template function/class has or a non-type template parameter of *non*-integral type:

```
template <unsigned int>
void Foo() {}

template <unsigned int*>  // Non-type template parameter
void Foo() {}             // of non-integral type

template <typename T>     // Type template parameter
void Foo() {}


Foo<10U>();               // OK
```

So if I had to guess I'd say it has something to do with the fact that the compiler can convert between values of integral types? But that doesn't stop C++ from allowing two overloading functions that differ only by the type of on integral parameter.

Comment: What's the point of a template if you use a specific type ?

Comment: Changing the second version to `template <signed int I, std::enable_if_t<(I < 0)>* = nullptr>` will make it work. (choosing unsigned version for positive numbers, signed for negative)

Comment: Thanks super, using SFINAE might help me with what I'm trying to accomplish.  Though this question is primarily about *why* C++ behaves the way it does.

Comment: Sagi, templates can have non-type template parameters which are, by definition, of a concrete type.  This is useful in many different ways which is why the language includes the feature.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It does allow it, you were able to write the two templates just fine. They just become unusable when instantiated. The reason is that there is no "overload resolution" to choose a template. The only requirement imposed on a non-type template argument is as follows:

> [[temp.arg.nontype]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.arg.nontype#2)
>
> A template-argument for a non-type template-parameter shall be a
>   converted constant expression of the type of the template-parameter.

And `10u` is a converted constant expression of both `int` and `unsigned int` type. Valid as an argument for either overload.

Comment: Thanks StoryTeller, that helps me and mostly answers the question as I had it in my mind.  The excerpt you cited makes it impossible to define/instantiate two templates differing only by non-type template parameter of integral type, because the template argument used for instantiation must be converted to the parameter type.  So, the two versions become indistinguishable.  So that is why compilers enforce this behavior, but I'm still not sure *why* the *spec* mandates this behavior (via the excerpt you cited) but maybe the answer would be out of my depth...