# enum as non-type function template argument should distinct from each other?

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, enums, overloading

The following code fail to compile/link in MSVC, but ok in clang++/g++, is this a undefined behaviour?

```cpp
#include<iostream>

enum class A:int{
    a=0,b=1,
};
enum class B:int{
    x=0,y=1,
};

template<typename Fn>
void iterate(Fn g) {
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        g(i);
    }
}

template<A a_>
void f() {
    iterate([](int x){
        std::cout<<(x*2)<<std::endl;
    });
}

template<B b_>
void f() {
    iterate([](int x){
        std::cout<<(x*3)<<std::endl;
    });
}

int main() {
    f<A::a>(); // actual f<0> ?
    f<B::y>(); // ok
    f<B::x>(); // fail to compile (because 0==0 ?)
}
```

may related: [Why doesn't C++ allow two function/class templates with the same name, differing only by the type of a non-type template parameter (of integral type)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52137055/why-doesnt-c-allow-two-function-class-templates-with-the-same-name-differing)

Comment: Always post error also.

Comment: Seems like a msvc bug.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it is a bug of MS VC++.

According to the C++17 Standard (10.2 Enumeration declarations)

> 5 **Each enumeration defines a type that is different from all other
> types**. Each enumeration also has an underlying type. The underlying
> type can be explicitly specified using an enum-base. For a scoped
> enumeration type, the underlying type is int if it is not explicitly
> specified. In both of these cases, the underlying type is said to be
> fixed. **Following the closing brace of an enum-specifier, each
> enumerator has the type of its enumeration.**

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a msvc bug. `B::x` is fundamentally no different(except it's type ofcourse) than `A::a` since `A::a` is of type `A` while `B::x` is of type `B`.

Here is the msvc bug report:

[MSVC rejects valid program involving enum access](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/MSVC-rejects-valid-program-involving-enu/10300933)